# Problems anonymizing apache logs

Tags: logging, debian, privacy, apache2.4

I'm trying to anonymize my apache (2.4.25) logs, using piped logs. I'm running on Debian9 on a vServer.

So in my apache2.conf I got this:

```
LogFormat "%t : %h : \"%v:%p\" \"%r\" \"%{User-Agent}i\" %>s %B" anonym
CustomLog "|/opt/anon_logs.sh" anonym
```

In /opt/anon_logs.sh I put this:

```
#!/bin/bash

# /opt/anon_logs.sh

# read from stdin
read logline

# remove the inner numbers of the IP with sed
anon=$( echo $logline | sed -r 's/\.([0-9]{1,3})\.([0-9]{1,3})\./.xxx.xxx./g' )

# write the result back into apache access.log
echo $anon >> /var/log/apache2/access.log
```

## Approach #1:

In my vhost's conf I got this:

```
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log anonym
```

### Result:

No change in the logs at all.

## Approach #2:

In my vhost's conf I got this:

```
CustomLog "|/opt/anon_logs.sh" anonym
```

### Result:

This is the only approach, that generates an error in error.log:

```
AH00106: piped log program '/opt/anon_logs.sh' failed unexpectedly
```

I guess, the script is missing sth, to be able to run as a background-process. Any help on this would be appreciated as well! But it actually does the job!!! In my access.log I now find the IPs cut down to 123.xxx.xxx.456

## Approach #3:

In my vhost's conf I got this:

```
CustomLog "|$ sed -r 's/.[0-9]{1,3}.[0-9]{1,3}./.xxx.xxx./g' >> /var/log/apache2/access.log" anonym
```

### Result:

No change in the logs at all.

---

Approaches 1 and 3 result in no change whatsoever. I find the full IP in the logs.

Now, if I echo a line from access.log through this script, I find an anonymized line in access.log.

The error.log doesn't show anything on Approach 1 and 3.

What am I missing?

---

mod_removeip unfortunately is no option, since it labotamizes php as well. And I still want to be able to distinguish between different requests/clients. I just want to have a nice compromise between privacy of my visitors and some possibility to be able to see, what happens on my Apache...

Comment: Turns out, approach #2 actually does something. Unfortunately only half of the job. The first line in access.log is as-is, and the second line mirrors the afore going line, with anonymized IP :-/ Any help greatly appreciated!

Comment: You should replace with `0` instead of `x` to maintain compatibility with most software that processes these logs.

Comment: Try `sed -E 's/(([0-9]{1,3}\.){3})([0-9]{1,3})/\10/g'`. Not iPv6 compatible, though.